# Create a new file in package directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `settings.yaml` file that will not be published with the package because of the `.gitignore`. I have an install script that takes user input and places it in `settings.yaml` so I can then import them in all my modules:

```
with open(pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "settings.yml"), 'w+') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

However, this does not create a new file if it doesn't exist, and instead throws a `FileNotFoundError` exception. How can I create a new file in my package?

Comment: What does the call to 'pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "settings.yml")' return?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was calling the `rescource_string`, which did not exist. The solution is to instead call `resource_filename`, which will then follow the default `open()` behaviour.